# PHP Activerecord Model Count Associations

Tags: php, activerecord, model, count, associations

I have three tables:

```
Member

MemberBranch

Branch
```

The `Member` can have many `Branch`es through `MemberBranch`. And a `Branch` can have many `Member`s etc.

What I want to be able to do is get a count of how many members a branch has.

so

```
$branch = Branch::find_by_title('London');
$branch->number_of_members; // Will equal how many members have the branch through MemberBranch
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone else has a similar problem, I have found a solution (albeit a little hacky)

```
class Branch extends \ActiveRecord\Model {

    static $has_one = array(
        array(
            'members',
            'class_name' => 'MemberBranch',
            'primary_key' => 'id',
            'foreign_key' => 'branch_id',
            'select' => 'COUNT(`membership_id`) AS `total`'
        )
    );
}
```

This creates a new association but does the SQL query we want using the select property. The number of members per branch can now be accessed like:

`$branch->members->total`

The reason I used `$has_one` as opposed to `$has_many` is that `$has_many` will always return an `array` of objects even if there is only one object. so using `$has_many` would have meant accessing the total like so:

`$branch->members[0]->total`

Save your keystrokes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.*, (SELECT count(*) as total from MembersBranch where branch_id = B.id) as total FROM Branch AS B;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would have done that normally but I am using ActiveRecord which is a library that wraps your tables with classes so each table row becomes its own object. I need a solution within ActiveRecord itself and not pure SQL.

Comment: My bad!  I though it was a regular PHP class with a static method. Question, have you add the $belong_to in your class definition?  http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/4/topics/438-foreign-key-conventions

Comment: I didnt use belong to but figured out a way of doing it. ill add my answer.