# count rows in each group

Tags: sql, phpactiverecord

How would one implement count with a group by operation using the PHP activerecord ORM? I know that I can do this directly via [`custom_sql`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders#find-by-custom-sql), but I am looking for a way to do this more directly through the ORM.

A sample SQL statement of the equivalent operation:

```
SELECT grade_level, COUNT(*) FROM SCHOOL
GROUP BY grade_level
```

Comment: I suggest you do it through a stored procedure and call that SP from your ORM. Please dont do it through the ORM as it will be very difficult to debug and support. Learn some advanced SQL if thats what is your concern. Its the best thing there is as far as db programming. ORMs are usefull if you need to support different DB vendors ( ORacle,MSSSQL,mySL etc)

Comment: There's reasons not to do this in ORM, but i'm not sure "difficult to debug and support" is the best argument against it. I _would_ suggest that a SP would be quite difficult to debug and support, as it would not be in your codebase for instance. So while it is somewhat a taste thing, I would not suggest a SP. (and how is a 'count' "advanced SQL?"). Anyway maybe this helps the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290934/php-activerecord-model-count-associations

Comment: @Nanne, I dont even think an ORM can implement all the complex functionality that can be implemented in a SP such as CTEs, TVF, complex SQL etc... And yes it is difficult to debug a ORM compared to a SP unless you have a very simple selects. Moreover SP's offer Security and an abstraction layer for your DB. MSSQL offers ways to step into a SP from your Code.

Comment: while count is not advanced SQL but it is unlikely that the OP has simple SQL like that everywhere else in his app. Atleast OP shouldnt expect that will be the case in all apps. Therefore better to learn advanced SQL.

Comment: There's so much context needed to even make that call. Suggesting SP and 'advanced SQL' for a question about a simple count is just completely random. You've found your hammer and now everything is the nail. Maybe the ORM on the other hand is the OP's hammer, but my point is we don't know at this point. So suggesting a completely different thing just because it's your absolute favorite doesn't seem like the correct sollution